# How to get blur edge

Tags: materials

I have a simple mesh and add 2 material (Green and white). Without jumping to texture painting can i make blur or mix both the shading so that i dont have this sharp edge between this colors.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to feather both the material and mix them. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Mix both materials in one material node tree, using the Gradient Texture. After that you can use lots of different techniques to get the blending where you want. (object texture coordinate and use empty to move the border line, Color ramp to control hardness of the border etc.).
Here is the node setup.
[image]

Comment: I did not get can u plz show me with the image how to connect the node and make it blending both colors

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking this because you don't like the shape of the edge you could also just add an edgeloop.

[image]

Comment: will still it has a edge between 2 colors